# Possibility of creating a new SSRS user using query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, database-administration

As we all know that SSRS user can be created using Reporting Manager which can be accesses by the url given in Reporting Service configuration manager utility.

But, my requirement is to create a new SSRS user ***using a Query***. I just want to know whether it is possible to do so or not. If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

something similar to this should work.

```
USE ReportServer
GO 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE loginname = N'loginname')
CREATE LOGIN [loginname] FROM WINDOWS
GO
CREATE USER [loginname] FOR LOGIN [loginname]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create users using the Report Manager URL. The permission management/Role assignment only can be done through it.

Adding Login/User to [ReportServer] database does not mean that user can access the reports.

The Group or user name should be a Windows domain user or group account in this format: `<domain>\<account>`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve your requirement of checking users' access in a query. First, in Report Manager, give all users the "Browser" role (for example, "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"). Then, pass the current user of the report to your database query.

The current user of the report can be retrieved with report expression `User!UserID`. In my environment, this is returned in the form `<DOMAIN>\<WINDOWS USER NAME>`. See [MSDN Built-in Globals and Users References (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more info.